# datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()) gives error

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

When i try to set the minimum date for the DatePicker view it gives me this error:

```
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.widget.DatePicker#setMinDate
```

My java is:

```
datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker_id);
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 259200000);
```

My XML:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_id" 

    />
```

How do i solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataPicker.setMinDate()` method was added only in android API level 11 (Android 2.3.4 I guess)... But in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you have set the `minSDKVersion=8` (Android 2.2)...

So obviously when some device running version 2.2 executes your code, it won't know about the `setMinDate()` method... Hence the error...

**To Fix:**

1. Set the `minSDKVersion` to `11`. But people with android OS less than 2.3.4 will not be able to install your app.
2. Remove the method and use only those methods which are available from API level 8.

Comment: Cool man, thanks. Now how do i set the minimum date without changing the minimum SDK?